# tinyDB storing images (or paths to them) and viewing them

Tags: app-inventor

sorry for the inconvenience, i am trying to build an app that helps autistic children communicate by pressing buttons (with pictures) and having them read. That works fine. The issue is about the menu - i want to make it possible for users to upload images via TinyDB (or at least paths to images that should be accessed). I've found tutorials about how to take a picture with the camera and store it on the SD or load such from the ImagePicker, but how could i make it possible for these images to be shown in the app any time it's on?

Answer (score 3):

[Do the tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/tutorials.html) to learn the basics of App Inventor!
In TinyDB you only can store text, which means, you store the path to your images there. For easier handling, you could store the paths to the images in a list and the list in one tag in TinyDB. To display the images, you could take a look at this [snippet](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#flung). You also can download the example project there.

[image]

Comment: thank you, the answer was great. I will try it out. I was reading/watching tutorials for three days just to find such a code but what you sent me was the best one i've seen (the canvas1 part). Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Instead of saying "thank you": here at stackoverflow you normally upvote an answer in case it was helpful. Also normally you mark an answer as answered in case it is, see also the [help how to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you ;-)